# Stack Matching Output Error

Tags: java, data-structures

I was wondering if I could get some assistance, I'm having issues with this created class the output is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Comparison {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        System.out.print("Please enter arithmetic expression: For example, the expression {25 + (3 – 6) * 8}");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        {
            String capture = input.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < capture.length(); i++) {
                char p = capture.charAt(i);
                if (p == '(' || p == '{' || p == '[' || p == ')' || p == '}' || p == ']') {
                    stack.push(p);
                }

                char r = stack.peek();
                if (p == '{' && r == '}' || p == '(' && r == ')' || p == '[' && r == ']') {
                    stack.pop();
                    System.out.print("Arithmetic Expression: has matched symbols. ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Arithmetic Expression: has mismatched symbols. ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter arithmetic expression: For example, the expression {25 + (3 – 6) * 8} 
{25 + (3 – 6) * 8} 
Arithmetic Expression: has mismatched symbols. Arithmetic Expression: has mismatched symbols. Arithmetic Expression: has mismatched symbols. BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Expected Output:

The expected output should be only the symbols in this case the output should read Arithmetic Expression: has matched symbols: (), {} as the code is popping once a match is found. The numeric values are of no concern. But If there are no matches - Arithmetic Expression: has mismatched symbols. (Then symbols).

Comment: The expected output should be only the symbols in this case the output should read Arithmetic Expression: has matched symbols: (), {} as the code is popping once a match is found. The numeric values are of no concern. But If there are no matches - Arithmetic Expression: has mismatched symbols. (Then symbols).

Comment: @nerdlyist I have added the corrections to the output. I'm fairly new to this site and I'm not sure how things should be posted.